# html tags in translated chains in Symfony and Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi and sorry for my english
I try to insert into translated text in `Symfony/Twig` an `<a>` tag, but it's not accepted by `Symfony`, whatever I use `| raw` or `| e` along with `| trans` filters.
There surely is a method permitting it, but I couldn't find it. Somebody could help me for this?
Thx in advance
M.

Comment: Can you show the code where you perform the translation and the translation file?

Comment: In the messages.fr.xlf file : 
`<trans-unit id="jumbotron.5">
 <source>jumbotron.5</source>
 <target>n cas de problème, nous sommes sur https://github.com/CRLbazin/agoraexmachina.</target>`
   </trans-unit>`
Of course, the link sould be completed with an `<a>` tag.
Calling this translation in the twig file : 
`<p class="card-text">{{ 'jumbotron.5' | trans }}</p>`.
Thanks for your helps !

Answer (score 0):

Way to add html inside xlf/xml is with .

***messages.fr.xlf***

```xml
<trans-unit id="jumbotron.5">
    <source>jumbotron.5</source>
    <target>n cas de problème, nous sommes sur <![CDATA[<a href="https://github.com/CRLbazin/agoraexmachina">github</a>]]></target>
</trans-unit>
```

For rendering translation in twig use [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html).

***template.html.twig***

```
{{ 'jumbotron.5'|trans|raw }}
```

---

For symfony you could also use yaml files. Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

***~/translations/messages.fr.yaml***

```yaml
jumbotron.5: "n cas de problème, nous sommes sur <a href=\"https://github.com/CRLbazin/agoraexmachina\">github</a>"
```

Comment: Thank you ! In fact, I forgot the escape characters ... so simple.
Just a last question : do you think possible to write the translated message in a  language such à Markdown and then get interpretated with the appropriate filter. This would surely be more simple ...

Comment: Should be possible to do with https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/markdown_to_html.html